# Regex matching not enough digits

Tags: regex

When I use this regex pattern:

```
.*(?P<midinote>\d+)\.wav
```

on these strings, here is what I get :

```
[ASR10] CHR Huge Ahhs1.wav     => midinote=1 OK
[ASR10] CHR Huge Ahhs2.wav     => midinote=2 OK
[ASR10] CHR Huge Ahhs3.wav     => midinote=3 OK
[ASR10] CHR Huge Ahhs14.wav    => midinote=4 NOT OK
[ASR10] CHR Huge Ahhs15.wav    => midinote=5 NOT OK
[ASR10] CHR Huge Ahhs16.wav    => midinote=6 NOT OK
[ASR10] CHR Huge Ahhs127.wav   => midinote=7 NOT OK
```

**How to catch the ending numbers (1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16, 127) by keeping an easy `.*` at the beginning (for simplicity) ?**

Comment: Why not just `\D(\d+)\.wav`?  You don't have `.*` at the beginning, but it's still pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use word boundaries and anchor `$`:

```
\b(?P<midinote>\d+)\.wav$
```

It is because `.*` is greedy and without `\b` it matches more than needed.

`.*` is not needed but if you really must use it then:

```
.*\b(?P<midinote>\d+)\.wav$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS9hR0/8)

---

**Update:** Based on edited question where there is no word boundary before numbers, you can use:

```
.*?(?P<midinote>\d+)\.wav$
```

i.e. make `.*?` non-greedy.

[RegEx Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/aS9hR0/10)

Comment: Thanks @anubhava! I just edited a bit the question (sorry for that), because usually I don't have any whitespace before the numbers. How to solve in this case? See https://regex101.com/r/aS9hR0/9

Comment: You can use `.*?(?P<midinote>\d+)\.wav$` [Here is demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS9hR0/10)

Comment: Waw, thanks ! I juste learned the diff between `.*` (greedy) and `.*?` (lazy).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `.*` at all, since it has absolutely no effect on what matches. And, as @anubhava stated, it's greedy, so it's consuming some of the digits you want to match.

Just simplify it to this:

`(?P<midinote>\d+)\.wav`

Comment: In fact I'm defining an "audio sample-set definition file format" (users are surely not familiar with regex), and I want that if the user enters `*%notename.wav`  then this is translated into a regex that will find correctly files like `[ASR10] CHR Huge Ahhs14.wav`.... That's why I wanted that people might use `*%notename.wav`